# Pairs $(j,k)$ for which $a_j+\frac{a_k^2}4\ge\frac1{2022}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2023}a_i=1$, and $a_i\ge0$, $1\le i\le n$. How many ordered pairs $(j,k)$ are there at most, for which $a_j+\frac{a_k^2}4\ge\frac1{2022}$?

I try to find the construction first. I can think of two directions.

The first, the values of (most of) all $a_i$s are equal. Solving the equation $x+\frac{x^2}4=\frac1{2022}$, we get a positive solution $\alpha\in\left[\frac1{2023},\frac1{2022}\right]$. So we take $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{2022}=\alpha$, $a_{2023}=1-2022\alpha$. Now the number of pairs desired should be $2022\times2021$.

The second, the $a_i$s can be grouped in two, one with big numbers, the other with small numbers. That is to say, we need to solve
\[m+\frac{n^2}4=\frac1{2022},~n+\frac{m^2}4=\frac1{2022},~m\ne n.\]
However, it has no real roots.

Anyway, I still have no idea how to prove.

Below is a solution!

---

We shall pick $2023$ pairs of $(i,j)$ for which $a_i+\frac{a^2_j}4<\frac1{2022}$.

Lemma. For $a$, $b\ge0$, $a+b\le\frac2{2023}$, we have $$a+\frac{b^2}4+b+\frac{a^2}4\le\frac{(a+b)^2}4+a+b\le\frac1{2023^2}+\frac2{2023}<\frac2{2022}.$$
Hence either $a+\frac{b^2}4$ or $b+\frac{a^2}4<\frac1{2022}$. Observe equations:
\begin{align}
(a_1+a_{2022})+(a_2+a_{2021})+\cdots+(a_{2023}+a_{2023})=2,\tag0\\
(a_1+a_{2023})+(a_2+a_{2022})+\cdots+(a_{2023}+a_1)=2,\tag1\\
\cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots\cdots\\
(a_1+a_{2021})+(a_2+a_{2020})+\cdots+(a_{2023}+a_{2022})=2.\tag{2022}
\end{align}
Equation tagged $(x)$ satisfies that the sum of subscripts in each bracket $\equiv x\pmod{2023}$.

By average principle, we find a different pair of $(i,j)$ satisfying $a_i+a_j<\frac1{2022}$ for each equation.

So the answer is $2023^2-2023=4090506$.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  If it is from a contest, please specify which contest.

Comment: It is an exercise problem. @heropup

Comment: You have a couple of mistakes: “$x+\frac{x^\color{red}2}4=\frac 1{2022}$”, then the equations in m and n at the end, as pointed in previous comment. Also your solution is there and correct, however i had a hard time understanding it. For the last part check my answer to see why unequal elements can’t check both the inequality and the sum.

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer and I have retracted it for now. I tried to see wether at least a pair of unequal numbers located left and right of $\alpha$ (in your notation) could check the inequality while the sum of all terms remains 1. The answer so far is yes-all 1011 pairs could have terms left and right of $\alpha$ thus all  1011 terms at the right could also pair to check the inequality. I need more time to finish the investigation but I encourage you to do the same check as well.

Comment: @youthdoo The problem does not require $j\not=k$. For example, $(1,1)$ is also an ordered pair. On the other hand, it turns out the essence of the problem and its answer is the same whether $j$ and $k$ are allowed to be equal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a pair $(j,k)$ good if $a_j+\frac{{a_k}^2}4\ge\frac1{2022}$. Call it bad otherwise.

WLOG assume $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_{2023}$. There are two cases.

- $a_{45}<\frac1{2023}$.
  Since $a_j+\frac{{a_k}^2}4$ $<\frac1{2023}+\frac{(\frac{1}{2023})^2}4$ $<\frac1{2022}$ for all $1\le j, k\le 45$, every pair $(j,k)$ where $1\le j,k\le 45$ is a bad pair. There are $45\times45=2025$ of them..
- $a_{45}\ge\frac1{2023}$.
  $$\begin{align}
  &\quad a_1+\frac{{a_{2023}}^2}4\\
  &\le a_1 + \frac{(1-44a_1-\frac{1978}{2023})^2}4\tag{1a}\\
  &\le\max(\frac{(1-\frac{1978}{2023})^2}4, \frac1{2023}+\frac{(\frac1{2023})^2}4)\tag{1b}\\
  &<\max(\frac{(\frac1{30})^2}4,\frac1{2023}+\frac{1}{2022\times2023})\\
  &=\frac1{2022}
  \end{align}$$
  Explanations:

  - ($1\text{a}$): Since $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{44}\ge44a_1$ and $a_{45}+a_{46}+\cdots+a_{2022}$ $\ge(2022-44)a_{45}$ $\ge\frac{1978}{2023}$, we have $0\le a_{2023}$ $=1-(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{44})$ $-$ $(a_{45}+a_{46}+\cdots+a_{2022})$ $\le1-44a_1-\frac{1978}{2023}.$
  - ($1\text{b}$): The expression at ($1\text{a}$) is a quadratic polynomial in variable $a_1$ in interval $[0,\frac1{2023}]$  with a *positive* leading coefficient, which must reach its maximum when $a_1$ is at the endpoints of $[0,\frac1{2023}]$.

  Since $a_1+\frac{{a_k}^2}4$ $\le a_1+\frac{{a_{2023}}^2}4$ $<\frac1{2022}$ for all $k$, every  pair $(1,k)$ is a bad pair. There are $2023$ of them.

In both cases, there are at least $2023$ bad pairs. Hence the number of good pairs is at most $2023^2-2023=2022\times2023$.

Moreover, there are $2022\times2023$ good pairs when $a_1=0$, $a_2=\cdots=a_{2023}=\frac1{2022}$.

Answer (score -1):

If the inequality holds for two equal terms then a possible partition of (0,1) could be created:
$$x+\frac{x^2}4\ge \frac 1{2022}\Rightarrow x\ge \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2022}}-1\right)\cdot 2$$

$$a_j=a_k\Rightarrow a_j\ge a_0, a_0=\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2022}}-1\right)\cdot 2\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow A=\{a_n\}_{1\le n\le 2023}=\{a_j,a_j|a_0\le a_j\le a_{j+1}, 1\le j\lt 1011\}\cup\{a_{2023}\}$$
$$\Rightarrow \forall j,k:j\le k\lt 2023 \Rightarrow a_j+\frac{a_k^2}4=\frac{1}{2022}$$

If all terms in A were equal to $a_0$, then the sum would exceed 1, therefore one term must be less than $a_0$:
$$ 2023\cdot a_0\gt 1\Rightarrow a_j=a_0, 1\le j\lt 2023\Rightarrow a_{2023}=1-2022\cdot a_0, a_{2023}\lt a_0$$

All terms but $a_{2023}$ are equal to $a_0$ and could enter a pair that checks the inequality.

**Therefore, the set A contains 2022 elements-the maximum number of elements that could be orderly paired into $1011\cdot 2021$ pairs to check the inequality.**

After investigating pairs of unequal numbers, the maximum number of pairs checking the inequality doesn’t exceed the finding where 2022 numbers were equal to $a_0$. For example 1011 terms equal with $a_0$ and another 1011 terms slightly larger while the sum of all terms is still 1 would also render the same number of pairs. In this case $a_{2023}=0$.

The only way to get a better result would be to involve the number $a_{2023}$. From the set of 1011 pairs of numbers equal to $a_0$ would change only one term in one pair to become
$$(a_0, a_0+x),x\gt 0$$

as a result of decreasing the $a_{2023}$:
$$a_{2023}=1-2022a_0-x$$

The question is wether the pair
$$(1-2022a_0-x, a_0+x), 0\lt x\lt 1-2022a_0$$
would check the inequality.

Solving for the ordered pair:
$$(1-2022a_0-x)+\frac{(a_0+x)^2}4\ge \frac1{2022}\Rightarrow x\notin (0,1-2022a_0)$$

Therefore no such ordered pair could check the inequality.

**Conclusion**

Given an undetermined set of 2023 positive numbers, some possibly zero but all being less than 1, with sum of the elements 1, there is a maximum number of $1011\cdot 2022$ ordered pairs that check the inequality $a_k+\frac{a_j^2}2\ge \frac1{2022}, k\lt j$.